# Illegal Characters in Path C# to Ironpython

Tags: c#, python, ironpython, filepath

I am trying to pass a variable that contains a file path to a `temp.xml` file from my C# application to my Python Script, but I keep getting the `Illegal Characters in Path` exception. I feel like I've done almost everything that is mentioned on Stackoverflow to fix the illegal characters/path on both the C# side and Python Side but nothing seems to be working. How do I get past this hurdle!?

Here is the C# code I'm using to open/replace bad characters and write `temp.xml`, to the `C:\Temp\` directory:

```
StreamReader sr1 = new StreamReader(filePath);
string tempFile = @"C:\Temp\temp.xml";

File.Copy(filePath, tempFile, true);
StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(tempFile);
sw.AutoFlush = true;

string xml = sr1.ReadToEnd();
string regExp = @"</(\w+)>";
MatchCollection mc = Regex.Matches(xml, regExp);
foreach (Match m in mc)
{
    string val = m.Groups[1].Value;
    string regExp2 = "<" + val + "( |>)";
    Match m2 = Regex.Match(xml, regExp2);
    if (m2.Success)
    {
         char[] chars = xml.ToCharArray();
         chars[m2.Index] = '~';
         xml = new string(chars);
         xml = Regex.Replace(xml, @"</" + val + ">", "~/" + val + ">");
    }

         xml = Regex.Replace(xml, @"<\?", @"~?"); // declarations
         xml = Regex.Replace(xml, @"<!", @"~!");   // comments
 }

   string regExp3 = @"<\w+\s?/>";
   Match m3 = Regex.Match(xml, regExp3);
   if (m3.Success)
   {
       char[] chars = xml.ToCharArray();
       chars[m3.Index] = '~';
       xml = new string(chars);
   }

     xml = Regex.Replace(xml, "&gt;|-&gt;", ">");
     xml = Regex.Replace(xml, "&lt;", "<");
     xml = Regex.Replace(xml, "~", "<");
     xml = Regex.Replace(xml, "&", "&");
     xml = Regex.Replace(xml, "“|”", "\"");
     xml = Regex.Replace(xml, "’", "'");
     xml = Regex.Replace(xml, "‘", "\"");
     xml = Regex.Replace(xml, "–", "-");
     sw.WriteLine(xml);
     sw.Close();

     ScriptEngine engine = Python.CreateEngine();
     ScriptScope scope = engine.CreateScope();
     var paths = engine.GetSearchPaths();
     paths.Add(@"C:\Program Files (x86)\IronPython 2.7\Lib");
     engine.SetSearchPaths(paths);

     var parameters = new Dictionary<string, object>()
     {
       {"scapFilePath", tempFile}, {"scapProfile", profile}
     };
     scope = engine.CreateScope(parameters);

     //EXCEPTION IS THROWN HERE
     try
     {
         dynamic result = engine.ExecuteFile("xccdf-xml2tsv.py", scope);
     }
     catch (Exception e)
     {
          Messagebox.Show(e.toString());
     }

     Console.WriteLine("Press any key to exit");
     Console.ReadKey();
}
```

Here is the code I have in my python script to deal with the `scope` varialbes defined above:

```
import csv
import sys
import os
import traceback
reload(sys)
sys.setdefaultencoding('utf-8')
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
xmlns = "http://checklists.nist.gov/xccdf/1.1"

scapFile = os.path.normpath(scapFilePath)

try:
    xml = ET.parse(scapFile)
except Exception,e:
    traceback.print_exc()
    sys.exit(-1)
```

Here are my current `scope` variables at the time of the exception:

[image]

Here is the exception:

[image]

Any help is appreciated; I've been stuck on this for two days now!!

Comment: Do you run program in which plateform (OS with version) ? If I am not wrong - in your filename may cause problme.

Comment: I'm running it in Windows 8, Visual Studio 12, Ironpython 2.7, the problem is identical when I run with Windows 7.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the screenshot with your variables

```
["outFileName"]
```

is displayed as containing

```
"c:\\Temp\tmp.csv"
```

so instead of the second backslash (before tmp.csv) it contains a tab chararcter

Comment: that was it, I had to change `outFileName = os.path.normpath("c:\Temp\tmp.csv")` to `outFileName = os.path.normpath("c:\\Temp\\tmp.csv")`; in the Python script. --Thank you